# How can I write a regular expression to replace hash-like strings

Tags: python, regex, windows, path

There are some windows names and folders containing names like:

> c:\windows\serviceprofiles\localservice\appdata\locallow\microsoft\cryptneturlcache\metadata\57c8edb95df3f0ad4ee2dc2b8cfd4157
>   c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\locallow\microsoft\cryptneturlcache\metadata\be7ffd2fd84d3b32fd43dc8f575a9f28
>   c:\windows\softwaredistribution\download\ab1b092b40dee3ba964e8305ecc7d0d9

Notice how they end with a string that looks like a hash:

> 57c8edb95df3f0ad4ee2dc2b8cfd4157, be7ffd2fd84d3b32fd43dc8f575a9f28,
>   ab1b092b40dee3ba964e8305ecc7d0d9

I am not good with regex and I would like to know if there is a way to write a regex that would replace these hash-like names within a path with something like

> "##HASH##"

The paths do not necessarily end with these, as these are usually folders/subfolders containing other folders of their own.
So my goal is to essentially get a path looking like:

> c:\windows\serviceprofiles\localservice\appdata\locallow\microsoft\cryptneturlcache\metadata\57c8edb95df3f0ad4ee2dc2b8cfd4157\some_subfolder\some_file.inf

to become:

> c:\windows\serviceprofiles\localservice\appdata\locallow\microsoft\cryptneturlcache\metadata##HASH##\some_subfolder\some_file.inf

Is there a way to do that in Python ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an [online regular expression tester](https://regex101.com) to fine tune the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you noticed, the "hashes" are 32 characters. (**IF THIS IS TRUE FOR ALL OF THEM**) Then the regex is pretty straightforward.

For example with the last string you posted

```
import re

text = 'c:\windows\serviceprofiles\localservice\appdata\locallow\microsoft\cryptneturlcache\metadata\\57c8edb95df3f0ad4ee2dc2b8cfd4157\some_subfolder\some_file.inf'
res = re.sub('\w{32}', '##HASH##', text)


print(res)
```

prints:

```
c:\windows\serviceprofiles\localserviceppdata\locallow\microsoft\cryptneturlcache\metadata\##HASH##\some_subfolder\some_file.inf
```

Notice how i escaped the \ with `\\5` that's necessary to tell python it's a literal `\5`.

The `\w{32}` regex means "match any word character Exactly 32 times"

Comment: The `\w` class includes many characters that are never found in a hash value.

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Now I feel a bit stupid.
Thanks !

Comment: Hello again,
I have noticed now that it also matches paths like:
c:\windows\system32\tasks\microsoft\windows\shell\windowsparentalcontrolsmigration
and turns them into:
c:\windows\system32\tasks\microsoft\windows\shell\##HASH##
How can I improve the re to say that it should have at least a digit in the name or k digits.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use a negative lookahead `(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]{32}`. If you need to tweak the regex further use this https://regex101.com/ you can edit the regex and see the result in realtime

Comment: Cool thanks. Do you think I could bother you here in the comment section if I have any other things that are unclear ?

Comment: Just a small addition.
Instead of going from a-z it should be form a-f as hashes in their hexadecimal format are in this range.
So something like: `(?:[a-f\d]{32})`

Comment: Yeah that's true. It's cool to ask further questions but if it's totally different it's better to ask a new question so other people can contribute :-)

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
import os
import re
uuid = re.compile('[0-9a-f]{30}\Z', re.I)

A = "c:\windows\serviceprofiles\localservice\appdata\locallow\microsoft\cryptneturlcache\metadata\57c8edb95df3f0ad4ee2dc2b8cfd4157\sub_folder"

path = os.path.normpath(A)
path = path.split(os.sep)
path = "\\".join(["##"+i+"##" if uuid.match(i) else i for i in path])
print path
```

**Result:**

```
c:\windows\serviceprofiles\localserviceppdata\locallow\microsoft\cryptneturlcache\metadata\##c8edb95df3f0ad4ee2dc2b8cfd4157##\sub_folder
```

**Note:** I am compiling for 30 chars in length. You can modify that value in re.compile